# How to fill missing data in excel time series

Tags: excel, matlab, time-series, missing-data

I need a hand on this problem: In an Excel workbook I reported 10 time series (with monthly frequency) of 10 titles that should cover the past 15 years. Unfortunately, not all titles can cover the 15-year time series. For example, a title only goes up to 2003; So in the column of that title, I have the first 5 years with a "Not Available" instead of a value. Once I’have imported the data into Matlab, obviously, in the column of the title with the shorter series appears NaN where there are no values.

```
>> Prices = xlsread('PrezziTitoli.xls');

>> whos
Name   Size   Bytes  Class   Attributes    
Prices 182x10 6360   double
```

My goal is to estimate the variance-covariance matrix, however, because of the lack of data, the calculation is not possible for me. I thought to an interpolation, before the calculation of the variance-covariance matrix, to cover the values that in Matlab return NaN, for example with a "fillts", but have difficulties in its use.

There is some code that can be useful to me? Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the statistics toolbox installed? In that case, the solution is simple:

```
>> x = randn(10,4);         // x is a 10x4 matrix of random numbers
>> x(randi(40,10,1)) = NaN; // set some random entries to NaN
>> disp(x)
   -1.1480       NaN   -2.1384    2.9080
    0.1049   -0.8880       NaN    0.8252
    0.7223    0.1001    1.3546    1.3790
    2.5855   -0.5445       NaN   -1.0582
   -0.6669       NaN       NaN       NaN
       NaN   -0.6003    0.1240   -0.2725
   -0.0825    0.4900    1.4367    1.0984
   -1.9330    0.7394   -1.9609   -0.2779
   -0.4390    1.7119   -0.1977    0.7015
   -1.7947   -0.1941   -1.2078   -2.0518
>> nancov(x)                // Compute covariances after removing all NaN rows
    1.2977    0.0520    1.6248    1.3540
    0.0520    0.5359   -0.0967    0.3966
    1.6248   -0.0967    2.2940    1.6071
    1.3540    0.3966    1.6071    1.9358
>> nancov(x, 'pairwise')    // Compute covariances pairwise, ignoring NaNs
    1.9195   -0.5221    1.4491   -0.0424
   -0.5221    0.7325   -0.1240    0.2917
    1.4491   -0.1240    2.1454    0.2279
   -0.0424    0.2917    0.2279    2.1305
```

If you don't have the statistics toolbox, we need to think harder - let me know!

Comment: Hi, yes i have the statistics toolbox, and what you suggest is actually a good idea. The problem is that i need to calculate also the mean for the log-returns. 
In fact, in the matrix of prices that I mentioned before I did: logReturns = log (Prices (2: end, :). / Prices (1: end-1, :));
on those logRendimenti I then used your suggestion 
SigmaMissingValue = nancov (logReturns, 'pairwise'). 
So far so good.
The point is that if I want calculate mean(logReturns), to get an idea of the expected returns, it is not possible to exclude NaN.